# write a program that creates 3 separate arrays of 10 elements each

Tags: arrays, multiple-columns

This is my code. The columns don't print out but the numbers do. How do I align the numbers into  different columns. One column of elements 0-9 and three other columns of arrays 1-3

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntroductiontoArrays
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    // put your code here

    final int max=10;
    int[] first = new int[max];
    int [] order = new int [10];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int x=0; x<9; x++)
    {System.out.print("Enter a two-digit number:");
        first [x]=input.nextInt();
        order [x]=x; 
    }

   System.out.println("\n"+"Elements" + "\t" + "Array 1" + "\t" + "Array 2"          + "\t" + "Array 3" + "\t");

   int[] second = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};


   int[]third=new int[max];
   for (int lcv=0; lcv<9; lcv++)
   {
       int a=(int)(Math.random()*10);
       third[lcv]=a;}

   for (int lcv=0; lcv<=9; lcv++)
   { System.out.print(lcv + "\t" + first[lcv] + "\t" + second[lcv]+ "\t"+ third[lcv]);}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you probably want the last `System.out.print` to be `System.out.println`. That way each call will append a newline. I'm guessing right now all of the output in on one line.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your loop iterates for 9 values, not 10 which being the case for `int [] second`

   ```
   for (int x=0; x<9; x++) // could be changed to x<=9
   ```

subsequently same for `for (int lcv=0; lcv<9; lcv++)`

2. As @Michael Albers pointed out, after all your effort your display might be ending up on the same line(row) since you are using `System.out.print`, should use :

   ```
   System.out.println(lcv + "\t" + first[lcv] + "\t" + second[lcv]+ "\t"+ third[lcv]);
   ```